# Stick-кнопка с настройками сайта на jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет.

Вот набросал такую разметку:

[image]

Как можно реализовать похожую систему с помощью jQuery?

Примечание: кнопка с окном должна перемещаться при скролле страницы.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держите [простой приерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/9Jp7g/1/). Дальше всё зависит от вашей фантазии.

Comment: @Deonis, уже в какой раз помогаете, большое Вам спасибо. :)

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте ей position:fixed через CSS, а с помощью jQuery обрабатывайте нажатия.